# NetworkPolicy with OR option in namespaceSelector

Tags: kubernetes

How can I write the following in namespaceSelector:

key=val OR key1=val1?

the following example is for AND, how can i write something for the OR option?

```
matchExpressions:
            - {key: app, operator: In, values: [application]}
            - {key: app1, operator: In, values: [application1]}
```

i find option to do OR between values (see below in the image) but not between keys.

```
{key: app, operator: In, values: [application, app2, app3]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `matchExpressions` the definition is that all expressions must match (AND). In official **Kubernetes** [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements) you can read:

> All of the requirements, from both matchLabels and matchExpressions
>   are ANDed together – they must all be satisfied in order to match.

You could add multiple `from` terms to your network policy, for them only one needs to match (OR). More on [behavior of to and from selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#behavior-of-to-and-from-selectors).

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it resolved your question.